# Invertibility of an ideal differentiator

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, homework, inverse

Is the system $y(t)= dx(t)/dt$  invertible or not?
If yes, please determine the inverse system for it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not. It suffices to find a counter example. Let me tell you that "I am flat". Could you derive my actual value?

So, any constant function $f(t) =c$ is differentiable, and have the same derivative, $f'(t)=0$. Only from knowing that  $f'(t)=0$, you cannot recover the original (constant) function. Hence the system is not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

The system is not invertible because you can always add an arbitrary constant $c$ to any function $x(t)$ and the system will map it to same differentiated function $y(t)$. So, the mapping is not unique or one-to-one and hence not invertible.

Answer (score -1):

Delta coding (with no quantization) is quite close to what you are asking. Let:

x=randi([0 10], 8,1);
delta = diff([0; x]);
x_hat = cumsum(delta);
assert(all(x-x_hat)==0);

But then you have a «silent agreement» to preprepend a zero such that you have a known starting point. And differentiation/integration is replaced by its discrete equivalents.

Knut